SOLVED - Silicon Mechanics Storform R512.7 with MegaRaid rebooting after accessing ~300GB on RAID5 array
I am running bacula 9.4.2 on an Ubuntu 20.04.6 Silicon Mechanics Storform server (server1). The machine contains a Megaraid controller with 5 10TB drives in a RAID5 array.
The bacula director runs on a separate server. When it tries to do a full back up of server1, it starts the connection to the bacula-fd process on server1 without trouble. The backup runs until about 300-400 GB have been backed up and then server1 reboots, the connection is lost, and the backup fails. Other incremental backups run fine.
I have looked at the journals for bacula-fd on server1 and there is no indication of trouble, just an entry for REBOOT and then the service starting again.
I have looked at the journal in general at the very end of the prior reboot and the last entries are finishing the message of the day and then a debian-sa1 command.
Then server1 reboots. The server runs fine for weeks at a time when one does not attempt this long full backup.
The termlog on the MegaRaid doesn't show anything askance. fsck on the file system shows no problems.
Any suggestions on how to further debug this?
ETA:
The only non-zero kernel panic is kernel.kexec_load_limit_panic = -1

Do you have any of kernel.panic... variables enabled (nonzero)? See with sudo sysctl -A | grep panic, especially ..._warn and ..._oops. Check RAID controller logs (google for "collect megaraid logs megacli"). And, to capture the very last system logs before death, try setting up netconsole (you will temporarily need some tiny machine nearby to collect kprints sent over the network); systemd was notorious about losing latest logs before system crash and this way you'll be able to recover them.

I expect this additional collected information to appear in the question, if you need further help.

I recommend to monitor while doing this backup. Especially watch the used RAM. PS the error might also be caused by a faulty power supply unit (PSU)

This is weird. I upgraded Ubuntu from Focal through Jammy to Mantic and now it works fine. No crash.

I’m voting to close this question because itself and the solution wouldn't be useful for anyone else.
